# Background image does not appear

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to put an image in the background but in somehow it does not appear at all.
I have tried to put it directly and it appeared: used code

```
background: url('images/image1.jpg);
```

but i want to use this css code:

```css
.masthead {
  min-height: 30rem;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 8rem;
  padding-bottom: 8rem;
  background: linear-gradient( 90 deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%, url("https://www.kinoundco.de/media/images/landscape_xl/blackwidow1_marvel-studios_walt-disney.jpg"));
}
```

```html
<header class="masthead d-flex">
  <div class="container text-center my-auto">
    <h1 class="mb-1">Black Widow</h1>
    <h3 class="mb-5"><em>Coming Soon On Flick Play</em></h3>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-x1 js-scroll-trigger">Watch Trailer Now</a>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: Did you add the extension to the image file? Like `background: url('images/image1.jpg');` or `background: url('images/image1.png');`?

Comment: Hello, i used background: url('images/image1.jpg');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put a `url` function inside of `linear-gradient`.

Instead of

```css
background: linear-gradient(
  90 deg,
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%,
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%,
  url("images/image1.jpg")
);
```

Is this what you want?

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(
  90deg,
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%,
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%
), url("images/image1.jpg");
```

---

By default, the `background-size` is `auto`, which shows its original size. If you want to show the entrie image. you can assign

```
background-size: contain;
```

to it. But if the ratio of the container doesn't match the image ratio, it could cause repeated background or gaps depends on `background-repeat`.

Most of the cases you would want

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
```

for background images.

Comment: yes, thank you very much. could you tell me how to fit the picture in the background, it appear only part of it